# Xcode 7.3.1 Fails to run simple app on device

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift2

Steps followed:

- Start XCode => New Project => Single View Application
- Project Name: TestMe, bundle identifier: com.testme.TestMe
- Selected Team under "General" settings
- Deployment target: 9.3
- Tried Running on iPad mini

Throws this error:

> `dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib
>     Referenced from: /var/containers/Bundle/Application/21F1FBB7-48A1-42B3-B740-EEF80C8722C2/TestMe.app/TestMe
>     Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
>       /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/21F1FBB7-48A1-42B3-B740-EEF80C8722C2/TestMe.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib: mmap() errno=1 validating first page of '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/21F1FBB7-48A1-42B3-B740-EEF80C8722C2/TestMe.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib'
>   (lldb)`

Comment: Is it set to Universal or just iPhone?

Comment: @Ike10 it's set to Universal

Comment: Looks like an error caused by _Embedded Content Contains Swift Code_ build setting?

Comment: Maybe you delete some library files...maybe. The simplest solution is to reinstall Xcode.